# Windows sometimes cannot find folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

This happens fairly frequently on my Windows 7 desktop, I'm manipulating folders (moving, renaming, deleting, etc) and a window pops up saying:

```
Item not found.  
This item is no longer located in: Filepath. Verify the location of the file and try again.
```

Then there's the icon of the file/folder and its name and date created.
A screenshot while trying to move a bunch of music is show below, and what finally prompted me to ask this question is that I didn't feel like clicking "Try Again" a few thousand times.

[image]

This has happened on an external hard drive, flash drives, internal drive, and everywhere I could think of. It doesn't seem to be related to any program I've got running, although I don't really know about installed programs.

Every time this has happened, simply clicking "Try Again" is enough to complete the action, and I'm pretty sure the files aren't locked or anything, but again, I have no idea what's causing this or how to fix it. I'm looking forward to getting helpful advice.

Comment: woops, my bad.https://secure.flickr.com/photos/109456842@N04/10989366245/

Comment: Did you recently add a virus scanner? (I got precisely the same problem which started shortly after I update my virus scanner. As far as I remember that was the only change I made that week).

Comment: not recently, though to be honest I can't remember when this problem started, so I sorta can't say it couldn't be it...I just turned it off and the window still pops up, I'll try uninstalling with a restart after finishing up some mp3 tagging.  I use Comodo Internet Security Premium (the free version) if it matters.